# RavenDb : Issue of matching with Search() and wilcards

Tags: ravendb, nosql

I use the Search() method with wildcards in a query.

**Example of my problem :**

To match the string :

```
uri:fooA:fooB:123.456.789
```

Examples of wilcards working :

```
uri:*
uri:fooA:
uri:fooA:fooB:
```

Examples of wilcards not working :

```
uri:fooA:fooB:123.*
uri:fooA:fooB:123.456.*
```

Is the problem due to the numbers in my wildcard ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, it's due to the choice of the analyzer for the index : http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/Csharp/client-api/querying/static-indexes/configuring-index-options

I choose the "KeywordAnalyzer".